# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLClientInfoException

Tags: exception

While installing opengts - have been running initdb a java tool. Initially face class not found error for mysql. fixed that and later have been facing "classnotfoundexception" for SQLClientException. I believe it should be part of rt.jar. However by adding above jar in classpath, has not solved the problem. please help with some pointers.

thanks,

C:\workspace_vilas\OpenGTS_2.4.5\OpenGTS_2.4.5>bin\initdb.bat "rootUser=root" "rootPass= "
"c:\program files\java\jdk1.6.0\bin\java" "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" -classpath "C:\workspace_vilas\OpenGTS_2.4.5\OpenGTS_2.4.5\build\lib"\gtsdb.jar;"C:\workspace_
vilas\OpenGTS_2.4.5\OpenGTS_2.4.5\build\lib"\gtsutils.jar;"C:\workspace_vilas\OpenGTS_2.4.5\OpenGTS_2.4.5\build\lib"\optdb.jar;"C:\workspace_vilas\OpenGTS_2.4.5\OpenGTS_2.4.5\build\lib"\ruledb.jar;"C:\workspace_vilas\OpenGTS_2.4.5\OpenGTS_24.5\build\lib"\bcrossdb.jar;"C:\workspace_vilas\OpenGTS_2.4.5\OpenGTS_2.4.build\lib"\custom.jar;"C:\workspace_vilas\OpenGTS_2.4.5\OpenGTS_2.4.5\build\lib"\dmtpserv.jar;"C:\workspace_vilas\OpenGTS_2.4.5\OpenGTS_2.4.5\build\lib"\gtsdmtp.jar;C:\workspace_vilas\OpenGTS_2.4.5\OpenGTS_2.4.5\otherlibs\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar;C:\workspace_vilas\OpenGTS_2.4.5\OpenGTS_2.4.5\otherlibs\rt.jar;C:\workspace_vilas\javamail1_4_4\javamail-1.4.4\mail.jar;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar";"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\lib\ext\rt.jar"; org.opengts.db.DBConfig -conf:"C:\workspace_vilas\OpenGTS_2.4.5\OpenGTS_2.4.5\default.conf" -log.file.enable:false -initTables  "rootUser=root" "rootPass= "Version: 2.4.5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLClientInfoException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:164)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:292)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java
:334)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:549)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:181)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.getConnection(DBConnection.java:606)

```
    at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.createStatement(DBConnection.java:71
```

6)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.createStatement(DBConnection.java:70
4)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection._executeUpdate(DBConnection.java:950
)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.executeUpdate(DBConnection.java:908)

```
    at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.executeUpdate(DBConnection.java:889)

    at org.opengts.dbtools.DBProvider.createDatabase(DBProvider.java:1422)
    at org.opengts.dbtools.DBAdmin.execCommands(DBAdmin.java:809)
    at org.opengts.db.DBConfig._main(DBConfig.java:1246)
    at org.opengts.db.DBConfig.main(DBConfig.java:1361)
```